# CRM Plugin Registration Tool Error - An unsecured or incorrectly secured fault

Tags: plugins, registration, crm

I'm trying to run the CRM Plugin Registration Tool for the first time and I'm getting the following error: An unsecured or incorrectly secured fault was received from the other party. See the inner FaultException for the fault code and detail.

I'm using the following for the Discovery URL as it's web based CRM: https://dev.crm.dynamics.com.

User name and label are correct.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue in registering new assembly.
My problem solved in this way:
1- Close current connection in Plugin Registration Tool.
2- Create new connection to server (login again). If you couldn't login, you should reset IIS or Recycle Application Pool or (at least) Restart Server.

Best Regards.